# ReactJS nested list collapse when expanding one item others should collapse

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to handle the click button item to expand only the item selected and all other items should collapse.

```
const lists = [
  {
    key: "inbox",
    label: "Inbox",
    icon: InboxIcon,
    items: [
      {
        key: "starred",
        label: "Starred",
        icon: StarBorder
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "drafts",
    label: "Drafts",
    icon: DraftsIcon,
    items: [{ key: "send", label: "Sent Items", icon: SendIcon }]
  }
];

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4
  }
});

class NestedList extends React.Component {
  state = { open: {} };

  handleClick = key => () => {
    console.log(key);
    this.setState({ [key]: !this.state[key] });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List
          component="nav"
          subheader={
            <ListSubheader component="div">Nested List Items</ListSubheader>
          }
        >
          {lists.map(({ key, label, icon: Icon, items }) => {
            const open = this.state[key] || false;
            return (
              <div key={key}>
                <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick(key)}>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <Icon />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText inset primary={label} />
                  {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                </ListItem>
                <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                  <List component="div" disablePadding>
                    {items.map(({ key: childKey, label: childLabel, icon: ChildIcon }) => (
                      <ListItem key={childKey} button className={classes.nested}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                          <ChildIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText inset primary={childLabel} />
                      </ListItem>
                    ))}
                  </List>
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

display list item and expect when I expand one the others collapse.
display list item and expect when I expand one the others collapse.
display list item and expect when I expand one the others collapse.
display list item and expect when I expand one the others collapse.

Comment: The code is not complete but it doesn't look like `handleClick` is a class method, therefore `this.handleClick` has no meaning. Also,  what is the structure of `lists`? It may not have any `key`, for example.

Comment: Change the `handleClick` event to `handleClick = (key) =>  {` and remove the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class NestedList extends React.Component {
   state = { open: '' };

   handleClick = (key) => () => {
      this.setState(state => {
         return { open: state.open === key ? '' : key }
      });
   };

   render() {
      const { open } = this.state;
      return (
         <List>
            {lists.map(({ key, label, icon: Icon, items }) =>
               <div key={key}>
                  <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick(key)}>

                  </ListItem>
                  <Collapse in={open===key}>

                  </Collapse>
               </div>
         </List>
     )
}
```